# How do I squash and edit the same commit?

Tags: git, git-rebase, git-interactive-rebase

When I do an [interactive rebase](https://git-scm.com/book/en/v2/Git-Tools-Rewriting-History) in git, how do I `squash` a commit and also stop end `edit` the same commit?

Comment: I had hoped to cleverly solve this by adding `edit HEAD` to the todo, referring to the newly squashed commit. But HEAD is resolved too early so it doesn't work :(

Answer (score 7):

Do it in two steps, first squash and next in second run of interactive rebase edit squashed commit.

Comment: That's exactly what I was trying to avoid

Answer (score 6):

Alternatively, you could use 'edit' to edit the commit, and then do e.g.

```
git reset --soft HEAD^
git commit --amend
```

Comment: This is what I typically do. I have a git alias `undo = reset HEAD^`.